# My ajax request isn't working

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an `<ul id="keuze_lijst">` , an input field with id `#sykje` and an button with class `.search` .

Now when i press the button i would like to clear the UL and repopulate it with data, for this i currently got this .js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".search").click(function(){
        var searchValue = $("#sykje").val();
        $("#keuze_lijst").empty();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.autive.nl/frysk/simulator/sim.php?action=getSongs&search='+searchValue,
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(rows) {
                for(var i in rows){
                    var row = rows[i];
                    var id = row[1];
                    var titel = row[2];
                    var artiest = row[9];

                    $("#keuze_lijst").append("<li class='mag_droppen'>"+
                                    "<div class='song_left'>"+
                                    "<div class='titel'>"+titel+"</div>"+
                                    "<div class='artiest'>"+artiest+"</div>"+
                                    "</div><!-- .song_left -->"+
                                    "</li>");
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

When i remove the ajax command and put something like `$("#keuze_lijst").html("hello");` it works fine. But the ajax command isn't working. Though the `var searchValue` does his work. (ajax uses the correct url). And when i enter that url the page echoes an fine json with multiple rows.

But in my page the ajax script isn't adding the `<li>`.

What am i doing wrong?

**edit:** added an jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/TVvKb/1/

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` totally replaces the HTML.  So at the end, your `"#keuze_list` will contain `</li>`.

Just execute one html() command after you build your html into a string var or something.

Comment: You are totaly right, .append() would fix the issue but that still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your updated code?  What happens when you build the HTML string and alert it to the screen just before setting it via. `html()`?

Comment: What happens when you copy your formatted HTML string into an `alert();`?  What appears?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance, I can say that the problem might be with your use of the `html()` function. This actually replaces the entire html content.

You might want to try using [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

Comment: As Darrrren also mentioned this, you are right but this doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Problems:

You are running into a [Same Origin Problem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy). Per default you can only make Ajax-Requests to your own domain. If you need to make cross-domain calls use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) or [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/).

Use the `html()` only once, and hand over your complete string, otherwise you will override your previous html all the time.

You are not landing in the `success` handler due to an error (e.g. invalid JSON).

Comment: Ill look into the same origin problem, replaced .html() with .append(), the json should be alright cause when i enter the url myself i get an clean and good json.

Comment: By default, it should be enough to declare `url:'simulator/sim.php?action=getSongs&search='` (only the path, not the domain!)- everything else might very quickly cause a Same Origin Problem.

Comment: Yea but the problem is that the sim.php is actualy placed on another server.

Comment: That's what I thought... for securityreasons you can't access another domain that easily, take a look into [jQuerys JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to make a jsonp request then.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think if you insert a string in the `.append()` and other jQuery methods, it parses to (valid) HTML first. That means that unclosed tags are closed, making your HTML invalid.

```
$('<div />'); // parses to <div></div>
```

So, I assume that your DOM ends up like this this:

```
$('ul').append('<li>').append('foo').append('</li>'); // <ul><li></li>foo</li></ul>
```

Please, just format your string first. You don't want jQuery to parse every input.

```
var str = '<li>';
str += 'foo';
str += '</li>';

$('ul').html(str);
```

---

For cross-domain AJAX requests (without JSONP):

**proxy.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(empty($_GET['search'])) exit;

$url = 'http://www.autive.nl/frysk/simulator/sim.php?action=getSongs&search=' . $_GET['search'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Javascript**

```
$.getJSON({
    url: 'proxy.php&search='+searchValue,
    success: callback
});
```

Comment: Tried it, but again no luck. I really think there is something wrong with the call or json results.

Comment: @Augus I'm getting an empty array as response at all times. The problem is most likely in your PHP. Also, is your test project on the same host as the AJAX request? Browsers disallow cross-domain requests.

Comment: It isn't on the same domain, but with php i don't have troubles getting the json back. Is this different with ajax? Try: http://www.autive.nl/frysk/simulator/sim.php?action=getSongs&search=beppe

Comment: @August yeah that's very different! An ajax request from one domain to another doesn't work unless it's [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)! It's a restriction that browsers have to implement to protect you from XSS. To fix it, you could create a PHP page that gets the data from that URL and echo's the output because your browser doesn't have any influence on your PHP. That way you can send an ajax request to the same domain (yours) and still get the data from another.

Comment: @Augus I have edited my post with an example that should fix your problem!